# How to propose a question as duplicate without closing it due golden privilege?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, vote-to-close, dupehammer

Let's suppose I think a question with `tikz-pgf` tag is a duplicate of another one, but because I'm not sure about it I prefer someone else help me to decide it. The problem is that I have a gold medal with this tag, so if I flag the question it will be immediately closed. What should I do?

Comment: you can always add a comment proposing the duplicate, and perhaps include some text giving a specific reason.  i believe that when someone checks that item and agrees, they will be inclined to cast a vote to close, and then (unless i am mistaken) it will be added to the review queue where it will get more attention.

Comment: Make a note/hint in Chat? Works most time to get the attention on a specific question

Comment: You can ask the question owner.

Comment: The real problem is that I forget that for certain tags I have this power. This is one privilege I would prefer to _not_ have.  IMO, it would be better if there was a follow up confirmation of "You can close this question or recommend it for closing and wait for other votes"

Comment: @PeterGrill Don't tell that to *me*!

Comment: @PeterGrill ***Yes***.  I upvoted this question because it is related, but your comment is the question? gripe? feature request? I really have ....

Comment: @egreg Don't you just work on the assumption that any question you vote to close will be immediately closed? I forget because, for me, it is rare. And I never remember. But I'd have thought you would not have that particular problem ;).

Comment: @egreg: :-) Yes, I can imagine that you have probably lost the privilege of _suggesting_ a question be closed as a dupe. :-)

Comment: Well, moderators face the same problem, but for any case, regardless of the tags. :P

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Such a feature has been discussed before on the big meta ([How Do I Opt Out of Privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231504/170190)). It has been rejected, with a very simple reason: **Nobody** (i.e., not even the casual voters) **should vote for duplicating unless they are 100% sure it is the correct action.**

If you are not sure, you should simply comment, not vote to close, and see where it goes.

Comment: Is this question duplicate?

Comment: @kando Probably yes, but on meta, we're not so strict about dupes...

Comment: Moderators have asked again and again for non-binding votes, and been rejected every time. Heavy lies the diamond.